# Ruby regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

Apparently I still don't understand exactly how it works ...

Here is my problem: I'm trying to match numbers in strings such as:

```
     910     -6.258000  6.290
```

That string should gives me an array like this:

```
[910, -6.2580000, 6.290]
```

while the string

```
  blabla9999 some more text 1.1
```

should not be matched.

The regex I'm trying to use is

```
/([-]?\d+[.]?\d+)/
```

but it doesn't do exactly that. Could someone help me ?

It would be great if the answer could clarify the use of the parenthesis in the matching.

Comment: Have you considered splitting on whitespace instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pattern that works:

```
/^[^\d]+?\d+[^\d]+?\d+[\.]?\d+$/
```

Note that [^\d]+ means at least one non digit character.

On second thought, here's a more generic solution that doesn't need to deal with regular expressions:

```
str.gsub(/[^\d.-]+/, " ").split.collect{|d| d.to_f}
```

Example:

```
str = "blabla9999 some more text -1.1"
```

Parsed:

```
[9999.0, -1.1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The parenthesis have different meanings.

`[]` defines a character class, that means one character is matched that is part of this class

`()` is defining a capturing group, the string that is matched by this part in brackets is put into a variable.

You did not define any anchors so your pattern will match your second string

```
blabla9999 some more text 1.1
      ^^^^  here          ^^^ and here
```

Maybe this is more what you wanted

```
^(\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*)+$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ulod)

`^` anchors the pattern to the start of the string and `$` to the end.

it allows Whitespace `\s` before and after the number and an optional fraction part `(?:\.\d+)?` This kind of pattern will be matched at least once.

Comment: "You did not define any anchors": what do you mean by anchor ?

Comment: @Cedric an anchor anchors the pattern to certain points, like the start of the string or of a word. without it you allow your pattern starting to match directly after your letters.

Answer (score 2):

maybe **/(-?\d+(.\d+)?)+/**

```
irb(main):010:0> "910     -6.258000  6.290".scan(/(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)+/).map{|x| x[0]}
=> ["910", "-6.258000", "6.290"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "    910     -6.258000  6.290"
str.scan(/-?\d+\.?\d+/).map(&:to_f)
# => [910.0, -6.258, 6.29]
```

If you don't want integers to be converted to floats, try this:

```
str = "    910     -6.258000  6.290"
str.scan(/-?\d+\.?\d+/).map do |ns|
  ns[/\./] ? ns.to_f : ns.to_i
end
# => [910, -6.258, 6.29]
```